# How to change a JS GameObject using C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Please help!
I have a Javascript component that references 2 game objects. The problem is, the game objects don't exist at start up and only instantiate when the player joins a network room.  The network manager script is in C#.
I need to update the JS script from the C# script when the player is instantiated.
The code I have so far...

```
            SpawnSpot mySpawnSpot = spawnSpots [Random.Range (0, spawnSpots.Length)];
            GameObject myPlayerGO = (GameObject)PhotonNetwork.Instantiate ("PlayerSHIP", mySpawnSpot.transform.position, mySpawnSpot.transform.rotation, 0);
            standbyCamera.SetActive (false);

            ((MonoBehaviour)myPlayerGO.GetComponent ("PlayerControl")).enabled = true;
            ((MonoBehaviour)myPlayerGO.GetComponent ("PlayerShooting")).enabled = true;
            myPlayerGO.transform.FindChild ("CameraCP").gameObject.SetActive (true);
            myPlayerGO.transform.FindChild ("LocalShip").gameObject.SetActive (true);
            myPlayerGO.transform.FindChild ("RemoteShip").gameObject.SetActive (false);
            GameObject test = GameObject.Find ("RadarMgr");
            Component test2 = test.GetComponent("3DRadar");
            test2.Transforms[0] = "LocalShip";
            //test.GetComponent("Radar_Mgr").Transforms[0] = "LocalShip";
```

This is the network C# script. The JS script I'm wanting to access, is the "3DRadar" component which is part of the "RadarMgr" game object. The "Transforms[0]" is the part of the JS script that holds the game object needed and "LocalShip" is the game object I'm trying to tell the JS script to use.  The last 2 lines are my failed attempts at assigning the LocalShip to the JS script. I did have other syntax instead of those 2 lines, but nothing has worked and that is just how it got left.
The other object needed would be the "CameraCP" object, but obviously if I could sort out how to do 1, the other would be done the same way.
I have searched for the last 3 days on here, unity answers and general google, but if the answer is out there somewhere, I cannot find it nor understand it.
I hope someone can shed some light on this frustrating hurdle!
Thanks!

Comment: What error do you get? It will help track down what you are doing wrong. Did it find the GameObject etc? Also try Component test2 = test.GetComponent("3DRadar") as component("3DRader");

Comment: I'm not sure if any of the last 4 lines worked to be honest, as I couldn't get any syntax error free for the last lines. I'll look at what the errors are again now, but I don't remember some of the syntax i tried before

Comment: The main error is to do with "Transforms[0]" and I get "UnityEngine.Component does not contain a definition for Transforms".  "Transforms[0]" is what I'm looking to assign a game object to. The JS script has this..."Transforms[0] = GameObject.Find("_Player").transform;" but that is a sort of placeholder.

Comment: if I print test & test2, I get "RadarMgr (UnityEngine.GameObject)" & "RadarMgr (3DRadar)", so I presume it's doing that part ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the syntax I was after....

```css
GameObject temp = GameObject.Find ("player(Clone)/LocalSHIP");
GameObject.Find("gameMgr").GetComponent<radarScript>().Transforms[0] = temp.transform;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring it as a component not a 3DRadar type. You must get a bit more specific.

```
3DRadar test2 = test.GetComponent("3DRadar") as 3DRadar;
```

I do not remember the exact syntax but I believe that is it.

or

```
3DRadar test2 = test3D.GetComponent<3DRadar>();
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer. If I use your example syntax, I get "unexpected symbol 'Radar' ". As far as I know though, I am already getting the game object and component but not able to assign my game object to Transforms[0]. I may be misleading you with the statement that "the last 2 lines failed"...I included the line that is commented out as 1 of the 2. I'm sure I only need to know the correct syntax for assigning "LocalShip" game object to "Transforms[0]"

Comment: @MajorParts: You probably have your UnityScript and C# scripts in the same [compilation group](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompileOrderFolders.html). That won't work since C# doesn't know the types defined in your UnityScript file until it's compiled. You named your component "3DRadar"? That's actually an illegal classname since classnames must not start with a number.  

Try placing your UnityScript (JS) file in the first compilation group ("/Standard Assets/", "/Pro Standard Assets/" or "/Plugins/")

Comment: No, it isn't actually called "3DRadar"...it is called a much longer weird name so I shortened it here for clarity. I was already told where to place certain folders and files of this asset if I was using C#, but I don't get to compile stage because of the incorrect syntax involving "Transforms[0]"

Comment: The problem is that you are assigning your script to a Unity Engine component. While all scripts are components a component has no idea about what you declared in your script. It is just the base class. 

The error makes this pretty clear. "UnityEngine.Component does not contain a definition for Transforms" Instead of assigning it to a component base class you need to assign it to a 3DRadar class.

Read the doc: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html you will notice that they are not assigning it to a component.

Comment: ok, I can understand that up until "assign it to a 3DRadar class". The 3Dradar script is javascript and doesn't have "class" as per a c# script (example "public class NetworkManager : MonoBehaviour". Is this even what you mean? I apologise for being a total amateur at this! I have read and re-read that doc, but it seems to me that "HingeJoint" is a totally different thing to a script component

Comment: Maybe class was the wrong word, you dont have a 3DRadar class but you have a script called 3DRadar that will work the same way in this case. You must make sure that it is a 3DRadar type and not a component type. I am not sure how to explain it sorry.

Comment: `3DRadar test2 = test.GetComponent("3DRadar") as 3DRadar;` is just another way of saying `3DRadar test2 = (3DRadar)test.GetComponent("3DRadar");`

Comment: I appreciate the time you've all taken to help me here but can we start again please? I've deleted the last 4 lines of code from the original that I 1st posted. Forget I even had any of that script. What I do have, is a javascript that manages the radar called "radarscript" that requires a game object called "anything" to be placed in "Transforms[0]". I then have a C# script that instantiates "Player". I then need to update the "radarscript" with the newly instantiated "Player" game object.